# how to move a plugin-block in Edit Post page back to bottom area?

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, post-editor

This is about a block in the right area in the *Edit Post* page of of a wordpress post.
It could be any plugin, but in this case it is about the **Analytify - Stats of this Post/Page** to demonstrate and solve this problem specifically:

[image]

Initially this element was at the bottom of the *Edit Post* page of the wordpress page.
But I did something wrong and it moved to the right side in the *Post* section.

I found a help page at Analytify for this feature
https://analytify.io/doc/view-google-analytics-stats-posts-pages-wordpress/ ,
but couldn't restore the original behaviour.

**Question:**
Where is the the setting on how to place this block either right or bottom? Is in the plugin, theme, or wordpress settings and where exactly?

Comment: You'll have to contact the plugin's support team. [Third-party plugin support is off topic here.](/help/on-topic)

Comment: @PatJ thanks, I changed the description of the Thread because I think it is not plugin specific. must be some kind of wordpress setting regarding the Edit Post page